# How to stop text from wiping background color with NavigationStack?

Tags: swiftui, colors, background, containers, fill

New to swift and stuck at the starting line...

I am simply trying to fill the whole background of a page using gradient. I have seen this is possible using `ContainerRelativeShape()` so have tried and it works well. My problem is that when I go to input text or anything of the sort after that, it creates a white background behind it.

I have tried simply filling with `Color.blue` at the start of the stack for example but the same thing seems to happen?

This is reproducible code to show what I am doing at the moment to try fill color.

By the way, I am making an app specific to iPad so unsure if this has some effect on the fill properties? I am using `NavigationStack` so the whole iPad screen is in use as opposed to the sidebar.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            backgroundFillView()
            VStack {
                Text("HELLO")
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("TITLE")
        }
    }
}
struct backgroundFillView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ContainerRelativeShape()
            .fill(Color.blue.gradient)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `VStack` which means all subviews will be aligned from top to bottom. Wrapped inside a `ZStack`, that assigns each subview a higher z-axis, can fix this issue.

Notes: name of a class or structure should be capitalized.

```swift
NavigationStack {
    ZStack {
        BackgroundFillView()
        VStack {
            TextField("Input here", text: $text)
            Text("HELLO")
        }
    }
    .navigationBarTitle("TITLE")
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks guys. This works perfectly, and great explanation.

Comment: Yeah, no worries.

Answer (score 1):

The items inside a `VStack` are shown in sequence, so this is why it is not working.

You can solve it by using a `ZStack` instead (see other answer). Or, you could simply set a background behind the `VStack`. However, if you want it to fill the screen then you will have to make sure the `VStack` extends to maximum size. Like this:

```swift
NavigationStack {
    VStack {
        Text("HELLO")
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .background(.blue.gradient)
    .navigationBarTitle("TITLE")
}
```

Note that by applying the background as `.background(content)` (using round parentheses) as opposed to `.background { content }` (with curly braces), the safe areas are ignored by default. See [background(_:ignoresSafeAreaEdges:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/background(_:ignoressafeareaedges:))